# making an Android peoject in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I have a problem. Today I started to learning Android coding but when I Make it there are a lot of errors and I can't fix it (my min API level is 10 , Target is 10 , and compile is 22 and theme is none) I use the latest version of ADT and Eclipse

```
[2015-07-22 17:17:40 - MyFirstApp] G:\WorkPlace\Android\Pr_1\MyFirstApp\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2015-07-22 17:17:40 - MyFirstApp] 
[2015-07-22 17:17:40 - MyFirstApp] G:\WorkPlace\Android\Pr_1\MyFirstApp\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2015-07-22 17:17:40 - MyFirstApp] 
[2015-07-22 17:17:40 - MyFirstApp] G:\WorkPlace\Android\Pr_1\MyFirstApp\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2015-07-22 17:17:40 - MyFirstApp] 
[2015-07-22 17:17:41 - MyFirstApp] G:\WorkPlace\Android\Pr_1\MyFirstApp\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2015-07-22 17:17:41 - MyFirstApp] 
[2015-07-22 17:17:41 - MyFirstApp] G:\WorkPlace\Android\Pr_1\MyFirstApp\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2015-07-22 17:17:41 - MyFirstApp] 
[2015-07-22 17:17:41 - MyFirstApp] G:\WorkPlace\Android\Pr_1\MyFirstApp\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2015-07-22 17:17:41 - MyFirstApp] 
[2015-07-22 17:18:01 - MyFirstApp] G:\WorkPlace\Android\Pr_1\MyFirstApp\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2015-07-22 17:18:01 - MyFirstApp] 
[2015-07-22 17:18:01 - MyFirstApp] G:\WorkPlace\Android\Pr_1\MyFirstApp\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2015-07-22 17:18:01 - MyFirstApp] 
[2015-07-22 17:18:01 - MyFirstApp] G:\WorkPlace\Android\Pr_1\MyFirstApp\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2015-07-22 17:18:01 - MyFirstApp] 
[2015-07-22 17:18:33 - MyFirstApp] G:\WorkPlace\Android\Pr_1\MyFirstApp\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2015-07-22 17:18:33 - MyFirstApp] 
[2015-07-22 17:18:33 - MyFirstApp] G:\WorkPlace\Android\Pr_1\MyFirstApp\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2015-07-22 17:18:33 - MyFirstApp] 
[2015-07-22 17:18:33 - MyFirstApp] G:\WorkPlace\Android\Pr_1\MyFirstApp\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2015-07-22 17:18:33 - MyFirstApp]
```

What Should I do ?

Comment: I would use AndroidStudio if I were you.

Comment: Have you tried with min api 10 et target api 10 ?

Comment: Include appcompat source in your source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to select Target and compile version 22.
because *Theme.AppCompat.Light* style available in *Support Library*
It my solve your problem.
[Support Library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html)

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of hard trying to figure what could be happening with that little information. Have you imported the support library ? [Tutorial here](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html)

You could start there. Also if you are starting i recomend you learn how to use Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions

1) replace all that themes with android:Theme.Light

or

2)  You can add Add appcompat_v7 Library to solve this problem

Comment: if you want to add Version Library  it will be available in 

sdk \ extras \ android \ support \ (version folder) \ appcompat

Answer (score 0):

Import `appcompat_v7` Library in your project:
https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html

Comment: Please add a little more explanation

Comment: way download appcompat library